# knockoutjs design pattern for multiple tabs and modularization

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have been struggling to find the best way to build/design an application layout I get pretty frequently.

The general build is a SPA with tabs for different bits of information. I use bootstrap tabs and a single viewmodel currently.  What I would like to do is modularize it better with a different viewmodel/component/whatever for each tab.

As a user interacts with a tab, their actions will affect the results of the other tabs.  IE tab 1 click sends data to tab 2 to refresh a table based on those values.

When a user navigates between tabs I need to save "state" or sorts/page/filter/etc.

I've looked into using things like knockout components, knockout multiple view models(with postman), durandal, knockout/require combo.

Any successful implementations or other thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried going to the vanilla Knockout route for SPA development and it gets challenging.

I would suggest using a library such as Durandal as it provides all of the necessary components for SPA development. Durandal uses Knockout as its bi-directional binding framework so it should be an easy transition. You will need to setup your routes for each tab and then style the navigation accordingly. Typically, I will use one view/viewmodel for a specific page. In your case, it would be one view/viewmodel per tab.

In your application logic, as you update information on one tab, you'd need to send a POST to your server through AJAX to update the 'state' of the other view models for other tabs.

Comment: thanks, I played with durandal a bit (not a lot) and felt like I was losing my "state" between tabs.  IE it would have to call the data again and I would lose my sort/filter/etc...  perhaps I just need to dive deeper.

Comment: If you saved your current view model to session or local storage, you could restore the view model when navigating back to the previous tab.